# How to make a security protocol in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I searched google for making a security protocol in LaTeX like this:
please if some one could help me to do that:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please add always an working example (MWE) to help us, to help you.  In your case, I still don't get the question.  I am not an security expert, so I  don't understand the given image.  So please describe your problem more verbose.

Comment: Looks to me like a table with math and normal text content. Did you try a tabular environment with p columns? Google should give you plenty of examples to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you look into designing a three-column `array` environment.

I will readily admit that I'm utterly unfamiliar with this type of notation. In particular, I'm not sure how to interpret/typeset the material in the middle column: Do the arrows and the material above them belong together closely, or should they be typeset on different lines? Please advise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose page parameter suitably
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}} % "variable name" macro
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\ID{\mathit{ID}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
\[ % start math mode, center the contents
\begin{array}{lcl}
\mc{\text{AHE}} & & \mc{\text{Meter}} \\
\cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3}
X_{\vn{AHE}}=a^{x_{\vn{AHE}}} & & 
  X_{\vn{M}}=a^{x_{\vn{M}}}\\
h_{\vn{AHE}}=H(\ID_{\vn{AHE}} \Vert X_{\vn{AHE}}) & &
  h_{\vn{M}}=H(\ID_{\vn{M}}\Vert X_{\vn{M}})\\
m_{\vn{AHE}}=h_{\vn{AHE}}\Vert \ID_{\vn{AHE}}\Vert X_{\vn{AHE}} &
  \overset{m_{\vn{AHE}\vphantom{y}}}{\longrightarrow} &
  \text{verifies $h_{\vn{AHE}}$}\\
  \text{verifies $h_{\vn{M}}$} &
  \overset{m_{\vn{M}}}{\longleftarrow} &
\text{computes: }m_{\vn{M}}=h_{\vn{M}}\Vert \ID_{\vn{M}} \Vert X_{\vn{M}} \\
\text{computes session key:}\\
  k_{\vn{AHE}}^{\vn{M}}=\dots\\
  c_{\vn{AHE}}=\dots\\
\mathrm{mess}_{\vn{AHE}}=\dots &
  \overset{\mathrm{mess}_{\vn{AHE}\vphantom{y}}}{\longrightarrow} &
  k_{\vn{M}}^{\vn{AHE}}=X_{\vn{AHE}}^{x_{\vn{M}}}\\
&& c_{\vn{AHE}}=\dots\\
\text{check if}&& c_{\vn{M}} = \dots\\
c_{\vn{M}}=\dots &
  \overset{\mathrm{mess}_{\vn{M}\vphantom{y}}}{\longleftarrow} &
  \mathrm{mess}_{\vn{M}}=\dots\\
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Kamto \dots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```